# Bootstrap select append function in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, html-select, laravel-blade

I am using a theme for my project. I am facing an issues related to append options in a select using jQuery because of theme's javascript.
When I append an option to select it doesn't show up although it is added. I found out that this is because a button and div are added above the select after page load. I am pasting 2 (different codes) for reference:

**Actual Code**
*The code I did in laravel blade template*

```
<div class="form-group">
    <select class="selectpicker search-fields" id="ct" name="ct" data-live-search="true" data-live-search-placeholder="Search value">
        <option value="">Contract Types</option>
        @foreach (\App\ContractType::all() as $ct)
        <option value="{{ $ct->id }}">{{ $ct->type }}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
</div>
```

**Code inspected in browser**
*The code when I inspect element the select in browser*

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="btn-group bootstrap-select search-fields open">
        <button type="button" class="btn dropdown-toggle bs-placeholder btn-default" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" data-id="ct" title="Contract Types" aria-expanded="true">
            <span class="filter-option pull-left">Contract Types</span>&nbsp;
                <span class="bs-caret">
                    <span class="caret"></span>
                </span>
        </button>
        <div class="dropdown-menu open" role="combobox" style="max-height: 590px; overflow: hidden; min-height: 158px;">
            <div class="bs-searchbox">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Search value" role="textbox" aria-label="Search">
            </div>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu inner" role="listbox" aria-expanded="true" style="max-height: 543px; overflow-y: auto; min-height: 111px;">
                <li data-original-index="0" class="selected active">
                    <a tabindex="0" class="" data-tokens="null" role="option" aria-disabled="false" aria-selected="true">
                        <span class="text">Contract Types</span>
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-mark"></span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li data-original-index="1">
                    <a tabindex="0" class="" data-tokens="null" role="option" aria-disabled="false" aria-selected="false">
                        <span class="text">Rent</span>
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-mark"></span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li data-original-index="2">
                    <a tabindex="0" class="" data-tokens="null" role="option" aria-disabled="false" aria-selected="false">
                        <span class="text">Buy</span>
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-mark"></span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li data-original-index="3">
                    <a tabindex="0" class="" data-tokens="null" role="option" aria-disabled="false" aria-selected="false">
                        <span class="text">Commercial Rent</span>
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-mark"></span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li data-original-index="4">
                    <a tabindex="0" class="" data-tokens="null" role="option" aria-disabled="false" aria-selected="false">
                        <span class="text">Commercial Buy</span>
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-mark"></span>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <select class="selectpicker search-fields" id="ct" name="ct" data-live-search="true" data-live-search-placeholder="Search value" tabindex="-98">
            <option value="">Contract Types</option>
            <option value="1">Rent</option>
            <option value="2">Buy</option>
            <option value="3">Commercial Rent</option>
            <option value="4">Commercial Buy</option>                                                                                                    
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Because of this, when I try to empty the select and append new options to it using jQuery with another select's on-change event:

```
$('#c').on('change', function(e){
    var id = e.target.value;

    $('#ct').empty();
    $('#ct').append('<option value="">Contract Types</option>');
    $('#ct').append('<option value="1">Rent</option>');
    $('#ct').append('<option value="2">Buy</option>');
    if (id == 1) {
        $('#ct').append('<option value="3">Commercial Rent</option>');
        $('#ct').append('<option value="4">Commercial Buy</option>');
    }
});
```

it performs it in select but doesn't show up because of shadowing button & div. I've checked the theme's JS page from where it is doing this but I can't understand the whole function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After making changes to the select, you need to call

```js
$('#ct').selectpicker('refresh');
```

as explained in the [bootstrap-select documentation](https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/methods/#selectpickerrefresh).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried giving z-index to your select element?

```
<div class="form-group">
    <select class="selectpicker search-fields" id="ct" name="ct" data-live-search="true" data-live-search-placeholder="Search value" style='z-index:999 !important'>
        <option value="">Contract Types</option>
        @foreach (\App\ContractType::all() as $ct)
        <option value="{{ $ct->id }}">{{ $ct->type }}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry but `z-index` is of no use here as the button (dropdown-toggle) and div (dropdown-menu) are connected to the select. These are actually showing up all options of select (before page load). But Thanks for the answer!